# unable to copy random generated values in to variable using tensorflow

Tags: python, random, tensorflow

I have data in one array say size [1x9] , I am generating random number 1 to 9 and shuffling it, I want to arrange data in that order.

```
# generating an array of number
BCI = tf.concat(0, [tf.fill([1,3],1),tf.fill([1,3],2),tf.fill([1,3],3)])
# making it in to 1x9 
BCI1 = tf.reshape(BCI,[-1])
# generating random numbers with length of BCI and shuffling it
rn = tf.random_shuffle(tf.range(tf.shape(BCI1[0]))
rna = tf.cast(rn,tf.int32)
# rearranging data 
BCI2 = tf.gather(BCI1,rna)

print(sess.run(BCI1))
print(sess.run(rn))
print(sess.run(BCI2))
# output is 
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
[3 5 0 2 6 1 4 8 7]
[2 2 1 3 1 2 1 3 3] # expected to be [2 2 1 1 3 1 2 3 3]
```

It because I am not able to copy rn value as constant , when I am running sess.run every time it is changing. 
But I need the random values generated in 'rn' first time generated as i need for testing on another ones. 
How many times i print rn it should show the same values with out regenerating again.
How to do it ?

I tried by importing random

```
n = tf.shape(BCI1)
rna = random.sample(list(range(n[0].eval())),9)
```

but it gives `ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using eval(): No default session is registered. Use with sess.as_default() or pass an explicit session to eval(session=sess)`
`

Comment: Add `sess=tf.InteractiveSession()` before your first `sess.run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tf.random_shuffle()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/constant_op/random_tensors#random_shuffle) op (and in general the other [`tf.random_*()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/constant_op/random_tensors) ops) will generate new random values on each call to `sess.run()`. If you want to capture a particular value for a random tensor and use it in multiple calls to `sess.run()`, you should assign it to a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops/variables#Variable). For example, you could restructure your program as follows to solve the problem:

```
# generating an array of number
BCI = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])

# generating random numbers with length of BCI and shuffling it
rn = tf.Variable(tf.random_shuffle(tf.range(9)))

rna = tf.cast(rn,tf.int32)

# rearranging data 
BCI2 = tf.gather(BCI1, rna)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(BCI1))  # ==> '[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]'
print(sess.run(rn))    # ==> '[2 8 3 0 1 4 6 5 7]'
print(sess.run(BCI2))  # ==> '[1 3 2 1 1 2 3 2 3]'
print(sess.run(BCI2))  # ==> '[1 3 2 1 1 2 3 2 3]'
```